# How to resize and delete an image on Mac?

Tags: macos, shell

I am following a guide to convert a .app file to .iso file on my Mac. I had to create an image and i typed the following line on my terminal

```
hdiutil create -o /tmp/Mojave -size 8500m -volname Mojave -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
```

Since there was no enough space on this image I created another and another and now I'm full of created images on my PC.

I would like to know if there is any way to resize an image from the terminal. Moreover i would like to delete all the useless images that I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
1. In Finder, open up your Macintosh HD folder
2. Press CMD+Shift+Dot //this will show your hidden files
```

Then navigate to /tmp/Mojave and delete the files you just created earlier.

```
Repeat step 2 to hide them again!
```

Comment: Are you sure is not there?that is what you are were trying to do when you used the command `create -o /tmp/Mojave` you are making a temporary file inside tmp(temporary) or try taking a look at your host directory